# Undefined offset: 1 in genghisapp on PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, rackspace

I've been using genghis ([genghisapp.com](http://genghisapp.com)) with PHP to manage my mongodb databases for some time on various servers with great success.
I've run into trouble getting it to work on my rackspace cloud server (fedora 17, apache 2.2, php 5.4).
I've tried with the last few versions of genghis on this server too without success.
I can't for the life of me see what I've done wrong.

When requesting the genghis.php page I get this message...

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Genghis_ErrorException' with message 'PHP error: Undefined offset: 1' in /www/engine/system/genghis.php:17 Stack trace: #0 /www/engine/system/genghis.php(17): Genghis_ErrorException::throwException(8, 'Undefined offse...', '/www/engine/sys...', 17, Array) #1 /www/engine/system/genghis.php(17): Genghis_AssetLoader_Inline->initAssets() #2 /www/engine/system/genghis.php(15): Genghis_AssetLoader_Inline->loadRaw('error.html.must...') #3 /www/engine/system/genghis.php(15): Genghis_App->renderTemplate('error.html.must...', 500, Array) #4 /www/engine/system/genghis.php(15): Genghis_App->errorResponse('PHP error: Und...') #5 /www/engine/system/genghis.php(36): Genghis_App->run() #6 {main} thrown in /www/engine/system/genghis.php on line 17
```

Anyone have any ideas what I've done wrong? Anything to point me in the right direction would be good. I'm notoriously bad at deciphering these stack trace messages.

Answer (score 0):

What this means is that in the file
/www/engine/system/genghis.php on line 17 some code Is referring to an array key that doesn't exist. "Offset"
refers to the integer key of a numeric array.

As you have moved this to a different environment it's possible that something that existed in the other environment is not defined and is causing the problem. If you can post the source code for genghis.php I could probably help a bit more.

Comment: [genghis.php source](https://github.com/bobthecow/genghis/blob/master/genghis.php)

But I highly doubt it's a problem with genghis, but rather something I've done wrong, or something strange with rackspace's apache/php setup.